# Integrate: $\int^1_0\ t\cosh(t)\ dt$

Tags: calculus

Integrate: $\int^1_0\ t\cosh(t) dt$

I am little confused when it comes to problems such as this. Do I treat this values as inverses of cosine and sine respectively. Or do I utilize these formulas when I am about to evaluate after integrating?

Where $\sinh(x)= \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ and $\cosh(x)= \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$.

[image]

Comment: No $\pi$. We have $\cosh 0=1$ and $\cosh 1=\frac{e+e^{-1}}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align} \int^1_0\ t\cosh(t) dt &= [t\sinh t]_0^1- \int_0^1 \sinh t dt \\
&= \sinh(1)- \cosh(1)+\cosh(0) \\
&= \frac{e-e^{-1}}{2} - \frac{e+e^{-1}}{2} +1 \\
&= -\frac{1}{e}+1 \\
&= \frac{e-1}{e}
\end{align}$

Comment: Can you explain your second line?

Comment: $\sinh(0)=0$ and by parts

Comment: sinh is the inverse of sin? so sinh(-1)=$\frac{3\pi}{2}$

Comment: $-1$ doesn't come into it, the limits are $0$ and $1$. Only think of $\sinh$ in terms of exponentials. Rarely do you use the correspondence between $\sinh$ and $\sin$

Comment: so $sinh(0)=0,\ sinh(1)=\sinh(x)= \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2},\ cosh(0)=1$ and $\cosh(x)= \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$

Comment: just put $x=0$ into exponential formulas for $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ and everything will be evident

Comment: I think here the actual problem is a lack of comprehension about what $\sinh{(x)}$ and $\cosh{(x)}$ are compared to the usual trig functions

Comment: @Sunny Are you not fully happy with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$\int_{0}^{1}t\cosh(t)\ dt=\int_{0}^{1}t\left(\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}\right)\ dt$$
$$=\left[t\left(\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}\right)\right]_{0}^{1}-\left[\left(\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}\right)\right]_{0}^{1}$$
$$=\left[\left(\frac{e-e^{-1}}{2}\right)-0\right]-\left[\frac{e+e^{-1}}{2}-1\right]$$ $$=\frac{e-e^{-1}-e-e^{-1}}{2}+1$$  $$=1-\frac{1}{e}=\color{red}{\frac{e-1}{e}}$$

Comment: @sandstone: thanks for observation. I fixed the error

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{1}t\cosh(t)\space\text{d}t=$$

---

For the intergand $t\cosh(t)$, integrate by parts: $\int f\space\text{d}g=fg-\int g\space\text{d}f$ where

$f=t\space,\space\text{d}g=\cosh(t)\space\text{d}t\space,\space\text{d}f=\text{d}t\space,\space g=\sinh(t)$:

---

$$\left[t\sinh(t)\right]_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}\sinh(t)\space\text{d}t=$$
$$\left[t\sinh(t)\right]_{0}^{1}-\left[\cosh(t)\right]_{0}^{1}=$$
$$\left(1\sinh(1)-0\sinh(0)\right)-\left(\cosh(1)-\cosh(0)\right)=$$
$$\left(-\frac{1-e^2}{2e}-0\right)-\left(\frac{1+e^2}{2e}-1\right)=$$
$$\left(-\frac{1-e^2}{2e}\right)-\left(\frac{1+e^2}{2e}-1\right)=$$
$$-\frac{1-e^2}{2e}-\frac{1+e^2}{2e}+1=\frac{e-1}{e}\approx 0.63212$$